# cant show the data from ajax after success in codeigniter in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

after submitting ajax i am getting the data bask but in console only the data does not in a div in codeigniter  here is the code

```
 jQuery('#npost').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        var url= '<?php echo base_url("user/postData"); ?>';

        jQuery.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
              console.log(data);


        jQuery("div#output_post").show();
        jQuery("div#data").html(data);

      },
            error: function(data){
            //error function
          }
       });            
    });
```

now

```
 $post = $this->input->post();
    print_r($post);
    unset($post['submit']);
    $this->load->model('Pmodel');
    $post_data=$this->Pmodel->post_data($post);

   echo json_encode($post);
```

but doing this only shows the value in console the success function not works

Comment: What is being returned in the `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found the solution for this i needed to get the json_encode data to read in the string form first in my ajax success. so i did this

success: function(data)
            {
              var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);

```
         var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

         json.textdata;

         $('#result_table').append(json.textdata);

  }
```

thus getting the value of the textdata that i want to show 
now wherever i want to show it just append the data to that div.

Answer (score 0):

If `$post_data` is running to the model, perhaps you should be returning the result from that?

At the moment you are sending back the original data sent from your ajax call... you cannot be sure that `$post_data=$this->Pmodel->post_data($post);` is actually running... typically you would have this function return what you want to display, and send back back using `json_encode($post_data)`

`jQuery("div#data").html(data);` will probably only output correct html, as the data its getting back (from what I can see is probably a JSON object `jQuery("div#data").text(data);` should work... though I cannot see anything to do with your DOM as the view isn't being shown to us...

Comment: after doing jQuery("div#data").text(data); i got [object Object] as the display

Comment: Because you're returning an object. You should be seeing the details of that object in console.log(data). Which will just be the same data you sent from the page anyway

Comment: yeah its the same data but in json form